# Batch file and CHOICE command for multiple files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, contextmenu

Having a Windows program that does wipe files and folders from the context menu too even with no confirmation at all then I created a batch file with the following content

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE /M "Do you want to Wipe Files"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO QUIT
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO RUN
:RUN
START "" "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\myexec.exe" /wipe "%~1"
EXIT
:QUIT
EXIT
```

and a registry key with the following entry

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\wipefiles\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MyProgram\\myexec-start.cmd\" \"%1\""
```

just to get a safety chance before to wipe the file or the folder and it does work.

However if multiple files are selected then it prompts you to answer `Y` or `N` for the times as far as the number of files is and furthermore the cmd window remains open until you hit `Y` or `N` the times as far as the number of selected files is.

Is there a way in order to answer a single time `Y` or `N` (closing the cmd screen) regardless of the number of selected files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no simple way to do what you request from the context menu, since a separate process is opened for each selected file.
But it can be done easily from the send to menu:
Create a shortcut in the SendTo folder for your script, and now you can send as many files or folders as you want.
The script reads as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHOICE / M "Do you want to Wipe Files"
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO QUIT

:: If your software enables file processing in a chain, such as myexec.exe /wipe filename1 filename2 ..., use this syntax:
START "" "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\myexec.exe" /wipe %*
:: If not, use the for loop:
for %%f in (%*) do START "" "C:\Program Files\MyProgram\myexec.exe" /wipe %%f

: QUIT
```

Maybe it's a bit of a deviation from the theme, but you can do it in VBScript like this:

```
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
if MsgBox("Do you want to Wipe Files?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "wipefiles") = vbYes then
  for each Arg in WScript.Arguments
    Shell.Run """C:\Program Files\MyProgram\myexec.exe"" /wipe " & """" & Arg & """",0,True
  Next
end if
```

It will display a graphical message box asking the user to confirm the deletion, without any terminal window.

Comment: The "SendTo" menu workaround does work flawlessly and with the same number of clicks and hits. Thank you very much!

Comment: I want to specify that the same number of clicks and hits occurs if you select a single file or folder, but if you select multiple files or folders then you save so many hits as much as the selected files or folders -1 are: a great result. Many thanks again!

Comment: VBScript does work great the same with both advantages that there is no terminal window opening with random position on the screen and that you can answer YES with mouse click too. I like it more than batch. Thank you so very much!

Comment: it's simple. After the "next" line, add this line: `shell.popup "Deletion complete!", 3, "wipefiles",vbOKOnly +vbinformation`. You can change the number 3 to the number of seconds the message is displayed (then it closes automatically).

Comment: Thanks for your appreciated reply, please note I unintentionally deleted my previous comment instead of editing it in which I asked if it was possible to make a desktop folder refresh (> F5) at the end of the deletion task since some file icons on the desktop do not disappear despite being rightly deleted.

Comment: It's simple too.
Add this line after the "next" line: `shell.sendkeys "{F5}"`